# Line spacing is extremely large in pyfpdf multicell

Tags: pyfpdf

I met this issue.
When I used multi-cell to output multiple lines of texts in a cell, the line spacing in the cell is extremely large.
I cannot find the possible function or parameters to tune and is there any buddy to solve this kind of issue?

[image]